# How to clear interval after status change in an API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

Let's say I have a `checkStatus()` method which is triggered after a response to an endpoint is successful. Inside this there is a `setInterval` like so:

```
checkStatus() {
    setInterval(() => {
      client
        .query({
          query,
          variables,
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status) {
            console.log("FINISHED!");
          }
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

Basically I am querying an endpoint every 3 seconds. Once the `res.status` becomes `true`, I want to clear the interval. The component is still there and hasn't unmounted yet.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use `clearInterval()` like explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear interval in your check condition.

Example:

```
checkStatus() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    client
    .query({
      query,
      variables,
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status) {
        console.log("FINISHED!");
        clearInterval(interval)
      }
    });
  }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to assign a `value` to the `setInterval` function and clear it into your callback:

```
checkStatus() {
    const intervale = setInterval(() => {
      client
        .query({
          query,
          variables,
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status) {
            console.log("FINISHED!");
            clearInterval(intervale)
          }
        });
    }, 3000);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first store the reference returned by ***setInterval*** and pass it to ***clearInterval*** to clear it. For example, storing the reference in a variable ***ref*** -

```
checkStatus() {
    const ref = setInterval(() => {
      client
        .query({
          query,
          variables,
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status) {
            clearInterval(ref);
            console.log("FINISHED!");
          }
        });
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a variable to the interval and clear the interval based on the condition

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  client
    .query({
      query,
      variables,
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status) {
        console.log("FINISHED!");
        clearInterval(this.interval)
      }
    });
}, 3000);

checkStatus() {
  this.interval()
}
```